# How to identify whether a coin or token runs on Ethereum?

Tags: tokens, ether, altcoin, polkadot

Hundreds of coins and tokens are listed on coinmarketcap.com, but how can you tell which ones are Ethereum-based or Ethereum-dependent? Hundreds of them obviously are. Is it only through one's own knowledge of each and every individual project, or are there tell-tale signs or indicators lying somewhere on the website?

Furthermore, wouldn't all Polka dot projects be Ethereum-based?

Answer (score 1):

You can view [ERC20](https://etherscan.io/tokens) on etherscan. This will determine if a token is running on ETH, as it will be an ERC20 contract.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way by any stretch, but this should work if you don't have the contract address for a token:

Check on any DEX like Uniswap for Ethereum network. Most tokens that are legit have a liquidity pool set up.

If a token is on Binance Smart Chain the token might be on Sushiswap or Pancakeswap for example, or for Polygon network you can check Quickswap.

Answer (score 0):

Any cryptocurrency other than ETH on Ethereum is a token. Any cryptocurrency which runs on his own platform is a coin.

Comment: "on Ethereum". you do realize the question is how to identify whether a token is on ethereum right